# Three questions about Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

1. Let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary nonnegative extended real numbers, with $x \leq y$. Is it the case that for any set of real numbers $S$ with Lebesgue measure $y$, 
   there is a subset $T$ of $S$ whose measure is $x$?
2. Let $x$ be a positive extended real number, and suppose $S$ has Lebesgue measure $x$. Is it the case that there is a subset $T$ of $S$ that is non-measurable?
3. Suppose $S$ has a Lebesgue measure of positive infinity. Is it the case that any superset $T$ of $S$ also has Lebesgue measure positive infinity?

Comment: Not a full answer, but 2: yes, by vitali's theorem. 3: yes, it follows directly from the definition of the outer measure.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1:$

Let $S$ be a set of measure $y$.

Take $f(t)= \mu(S \cap (-t, t))$.

$f(t)$ is continuous in $[0, \infty]$:
for any $\epsilon$, take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and then

$|f(t+\delta)-f(t)| = \mu(S \cap [(-t-\delta, -t) \cup (t, t+\delta)]) \leq 2\delta=\epsilon$

(this assumes $\delta > 0$, but a similar argument works when $\delta < 0$).

Now, $f(t)$ is also monotonous, so $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} f(t)$ exists (finite or infinite). But $\mu(S \cap (-\infty, \infty))=y$, therefore $\lim \limits_{t \to \infty} f(t) = y$.

$f(0)=0$.

By the intermediate value theorem, $f$ reaches any value between $0$ and $y$.